# Why $\ln 2=\ln 1.075^t\implies \ln 2=t\ln 1.075$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Why $$\ln 2=\ln 1.075^t\implies \ln 2=t\ln 1.075$$

Comment: It is also valid in the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From definition we have:

$a=e^{\ln{a}}$

$a^{b}=e^{\ln(a^{b})}$

$a^{b}=(e^{\ln{a}})^{b}=e^{b\ln{a}}$    thus

$e^{\ln(a^{b})}=e^{b\ln{a}}$     $\;\iff\;$
$\ln(a^{b})=b\ln{a}$

The last follows from the injectivity of the function 
$e^{x}$.

Answer (score 4):

That follows from one of the laws of logarithms:

$$\ln a^b = b\ln a \tag{$*$}$$

In your case $a=1.075, \; b=t$.

$(*)$ Note that this holds for $\log a^b$, in general, not just the natural log.

Comment: But I want proof for it

Comment: It follows from the [definition of the logarithm,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithms) and can also be justified by [simple arithmetic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities)

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific form of logarithms of powers, or $log_b(x^r) = r\cdot log_b(x)$. To prove this statement, let $y=r\cdot log_b(x)$. Then,
$$
b^y = b^{r\cdot log_b(x)} \\
b^y = (b^{log_b(x)})^r \\
b^y = x^r \\
log_b(b^y) = log_b(x^r) \\
y = log_b(x^r)
$$

Therefore, the original statement is proved. Your specific example follows for $x=1.075$, $b=e$, and $r=t$ since setting both equations equal to $ln(2)$ reduces to $ln(1.075^t) = t\cdot ln(1.075)$.